# map.fitBounds works weird when map has 'restriction' option set

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have 2 markers on a map. I want to make those two markers visible on the map when some event happens. But when I add `restriction` option on map `fitBounds` does not show markers. When I remove `restriction` option it seems to work correctly.
Here is the sample code:

```js
var map, markers;

var locations = [{
    lat: 50.8503396,
    lng: 4.351710300000036
  },
  {
    lat: 49.9570366,
    lng: 36.3431478
  },
];

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 1,
    center: {
      lat: -28.024,
      lng: 140.887
    },
    restriction: {
      strictBounds: true,
      latLngBounds: {
        north: 85,
        south: -85,
        west: -180,
        east: 180
      },
    },
  });

  markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
    return new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location
    });
  });

  markers.forEach(function(marker) {
    marker.setMap(map);
  });
}


setTimeout(function() {
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  markers.forEach(function(marker) {
    bounds.extend(marker.position);
  });
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}, 5000);
```

```css
#map {
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fedman/6eoty0vm/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a bug. It works fine with version 3.34 of the API as shown in the code below. Seems to work also fine depending on the map container height (tried with a height of 200px and it worked even with the latest versions).

I have opened a [bug in the issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/124546317).

```js
var map, markers;

var locations = [{
    lat: 50.8503396,
    lng: 4.351710300000036
  },
  {
    lat: 49.9570366,
    lng: 36.3431478
  },
];

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 1,
    center: {
      lat: -28.024,
      lng: 140.887
    },
    restriction: {
      strictBounds: true,
      latLngBounds: {
        north: 85,
        south: -85,
        west: -180,
        east: 180
      },
    },
  });

  markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
    return new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location
    });
  });

  markers.forEach(function(marker) {
    marker.setMap(map);
  });
}


setTimeout(function() {
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  markers.forEach(function(marker) {
    bounds.extend(marker.position);
  });
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}, 5000);
```

```css
#map {
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.34&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. Google maps API v3.34 does not have `restriction` option. That is why it works. If zoom out in your example grey area appears. I was trying to get rid of it by using the option.

Comment: Right. I didn't even check that... Still the bug is reported so Google should take action soon (hopefully).

Answer (score 5):

While this bug of google.maps.api still exists you can set map center to bounds center as a workaround.

```
map.fitBounds(bounds);
map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
```

Comment: Apparently calling `fitBounds()` twice also does the trick. Sounds like a small issue that wasn't present in previous versions of the API, still, the issue was opened almost 2 years ago with Google and it's still not fixed.